# How can I automate data verification tests on PowerBi Dashboards?

Tags: selenium, testing, automation, ssms, powerbi

I'm part of a small project where we have a Data Warehouse and produce PowerBi dashboards which show different kinds of data stored in the warehouse.

For example we could have a dashboard visual that shows the type and cost of each claim (e.g. A Theft claim for £1000) In table form.

My question is, are there anyway ways of creating automation test scripts so that we can check the data sums displayed on the powerBi dashboards are correct?

I could potentially create a test script that compared the data in the base query of the dashboard - but that would be before the DAX calculations were made which then the outputs are shown on the powerBi visuals.
Is selenium a possibility?

Answer (score 1):

Selenium is a possibility. I worked at a client with a similar need, a data warehouse that reports pulled data from and filtered or aggregated before displaying. We built a test framework to test both the data warehouse (test that data was being loaded and transformed into the right places) and the Power BI reports, where we used Selenium to pull data from the charts and compare them to the result of a SQL query against the data warehouse.

I've got a few recommendations if you do go down that path though:

- Try and use Power BI's "export to csv/Excel" functionality (located in the visual header's overflow menu) because extracting values from some charts can be really tricky. For example, clustered bar charts can be a real pain because you're dealing with values that are clustered a certain X coordinate.
- If you can't export the data, the next best approach would be to use the "Show as table" option that most charts have. This will format any visual's data into a table, that is much easier to extract data from than the charts themselves. There are some things you'll have to watch out for though, like some tables that will cram all of their column headings into the corner cell and separate them with commas!
- Get your developers to use alt-text everywhere as it will make your selectors much easier. Once you've got them putting unique alt-text on all of your charts, you can usually just use a CSS selector that looks for an element with an 'aria-label' attribute equal to that alt-text. Most of my framework is built around that.
- Make liberal use of dynamic waits (the WebDriverWait class is great for this) as Power BI will load a report page but the charts will still be waiting for their query results from the service before rendering.

Using Selenium is definitely an option. It can be a little challenging in that you need to figure out how to scale it as your number of tests grow and you have to deal with the skillset requirement that can be distinct from the rest of your team. I built [PowerTester](https://www.powertester.app/) to get around some of these because the Selenium framework eventually became a bottleneck on the amount of work my team could get through in each sprint.